# Optimize Subquery in Join

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM s
JOIN b ON s.borrowerId = b.id
JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(id) AS id
    FROM tbl
    WHERE dealId IS NULL
    GROUP BY borrowerId, created
) s2 ON s.id = s2.id
```

Is there a simple way to optimize this so that I can do the JOIN directly and utilize indexes?

**UPDATE**

The `created` field is part of the `GROUP BY` statement because due to the limitations of our version of MySQL and the ORM being used it is possible to have multiple records with the same `created` timestamp value. As a result I need to find the first record for each combination of `borrowerId` and `created`.

Typically I might attempt something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM s
INNER JOIN b ON s.borrowerId = b.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN s2
    ON s.borrowerId = s2.borrowerId
    AND s.created = s2.created
    AND s.id <> s2.id
    AND s.id < s2.id
WHERE s2.id IS NULL
AND s.dealId IS NULL;
```

But I'm not sure if that works 100% the way I want.

EXPLAIN from MySQL outputs the following:

```
1   PRIMARY b   ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    129690  
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  ALL NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    317751  Using join buffer
1   PRIMARY s   eq_ref  PRIMARY,borrowerId_2,borrowerId PRIMARY 4   s2.id   1   Using where
2   DERIVED statuses    ref dealId  dealId  5       183987  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

As you can see, it has to query a massive number of records to build the subquery data set and when joining to the derived subquery, no indexes are found and so no indexes are used.

Comment: What's wrong with it like this? Can you post the query plan?

Comment: Do you really intend for `created` to be int he `GROUP BY`?  What do you want this query to do?  Sample data and desired results would help explain your intention.

Comment: This will make use of indexes. The subquery will use indexes on the `userId` and `created` columns, and the join will use the index on the `id` column to match with the temporary.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I provided additional information as you requested.

Comment: @Vatev Results from EXPLAIN are posted. Hopefully it is now clear what is wrong with the current query plan.

Comment: What indexes do you have on the table? I think a composite index on `(borrowerId, created, id)` should make the subquery efficient.

Answer (score 0):

The first query needs this composite index:

```
INDEX(borrowerId, created, id)
```

Note that MySQL rarely uses two indexes for one `SELECT`, but a composite index is often very handy.

The second query seems grossly inefficient.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Comment: Apologies to @Barmar -- if he makes his comment an Answer, he should get credit.